# vaadin grid column sort for nested properties

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-grid, vaadin14

I use Vaadin grid with nested properties, e.g. `order.createdAt`. I want to sort such columns and set sorting with `.setSortProperty("order.createdAt")` due to `createdAt`is an LocalDateTime which is always `Comparable`. But this doesn't work. I need to define a `comparator`for every such column, and I've use a lot of them :-)

```java
grid.addColumn(new LocalDateTimeRenderer<>(dto -> 
  dto.getOrder().getCreatedAt(), DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.SHORT)))
 .setAutoWidth(true)
 .setFlexGrow(0)
 .setHeader("Order data")
 //.setSortProperty("order.createdAt") <-- doesn't work
 .setComparator((val1, val2) -> val1.getOrder().getCreatedAt().compareTo(val2.getOrder().getCreatedAt()))
            .setSortable(true);
```

Is this a bug or it is intentionally ?

Kind regards
Dominik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's intentional. As the feature is currently defined the [Comparator](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/20.0.3/com/vaadin/flow/component/grid/Grid.Column.html#setComparator-java.util.Comparator-) is used for in-memory sorting, and [sortProperty](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/20.0.3/com/vaadin/flow/component/grid/Grid.Column.html#setSortProperty-java.lang.String...-) applies when using a backend DataProvider.

You can, however, use the `setComparator` variant that takes a `ValueProvider` to make the code slightly shorter: `setComparator(dto -> dto.getOrder().getCreatedAt())`. Furthermore, column is marked as sortable through `setComparator` so don't need to separately do `setSortable(true)`.