# vaadin grid sort bigDecimal column

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-grid, vaadin14

I've add a column for a BigDecimal property into the grid and expect that sorting for such column works out-of-the-box:

```java
grid.addColumn(new NumberRenderer<>(dto -> dto.getTotalPrice(), NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance()))
    .setAutoWidth(true)
    .setFlexGrow(0)
    .setHeader("Summe")
    .setSortProperty("totalPrice") 
    .setSortable(true);
```

But this doesn't work and I've to provide the comparator

```java
.setComparator((val1, val2) -> val1.getTotalPrice().compareTo(val2.getTotalPrice()))
```

Maybe similar issue like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68037219/vaadin-grid-column-sort-for-nested-properties)

**Addition**:
If I go without the NumberRenderer and add the column the normal way, then setSortedProperty works as expected:

```java
grid.addColumn(OrderListDto::getTotalPrice, "totalPrice")
    .setSortProperty("totalPrice")
```

Comment: If I go without the NumberRenderer and add the column normal styled like grid.addColumn(OrderListDto::getTotalPrice, "totalPrice")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't define a renderer, then the value provider that you define for the column will also be used for comparing in-memory values if sorting is enabled for the column. When you use a renderer, then the column doesn't have direct access to the value provider that you give to the renderer, so you instead need to define it manually.

The value that you pass to `setSortProperty` is only used by backend data providers, but not for in-memory data. It may still give the impression of working since `setSortProperty` also triggers `setSortable(true)` which will work when no renderer is used based on the value provider. The value that you pass to `setSortProperty` does not have any effect with in-memory data, so you could do `setSortProperty("foo")` and the result would be the same.

Comment: Ok, I understand the principle. For every column with a renderer, I need to provide a comparator as well. And there is a distinction between in-memory and backend based data provider. I suggest to clarify such details within the documentation.